# Symfony Factory class

Tags: symfony, factory

I would like to use a ResultFactory class as a service in my Symfony 2 application:

My Result factory class will be responsible to create a BaseResult instance.
Depending on the type passed to the get factory method, the ResultFactory will create the right ResultObject.

Here's what could be the code:

```
class ResultFactory
{

    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator) 
    { 
        $this->translator = $translator;
    } 

    public function get($type, $param)
    {
        $instance = null;

        switch ($type) {

            case 'Type1':
                $instance = new Type1Result($param);
                break;

            case 'Type2':
                $instance = new Type2Result($param);
                break;

        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

My question is:

I would like to use a service in my ResultObject. How do i inject this service to my ResultObject?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please clarify how you'd like to inject the service into the resultobject before returning it ? setter- or contructur-injection ... ? `$instance->setService($service)` or `new Instance($service, $param)` ? It's not quite clear what you want as it seems you're already injecting the translator service ... why not just pass the service you want to inject into the returnobject as an additional argument to the factory and pass it through?

Comment: I don't know which way i'd like to use to inject the service. I just want to be able to use some services into my Result classes. I was not sure it was the right way to do, passing it as argument to the instance constructor and store it in my base class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using your service inside a result object. your factory is generating the result object.
You can define your factory service in services.yml of your bundle as:

```
result.factory:
    class: ResultFactory
    arguments: ["@translator"]
```

And in your controller you can call the service:

```
 $resultObject = $this->get('result_factory')->get($type, $param);
```

Also you have core example how to create factory service using symfony2 in [the docs].(http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)